# how to restrict the print values inside groovy each closure?

Tags: collections, groovy

in groovy loop like :

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
  x.each { i ->
            // other CRUD type functionality - required
            // print each values - not required
  }
```

Can I restrict the print values inside the each clause. Actually I want the CRUD functionality to execute. But after that print i prints each values which I don't want.

my output as of now :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
==>1
==>2
==>3
==>4
==>5
==>6
```

Comment: Do you mean in the groovy console? Where it shows you the value of `x` in yellow on black text when the script has finished?

Comment: i updated my post with my current output..I don't want these ==> * values to appear.

Comment: Do you print them out? I can't see how they are appearing from your question

Comment: yes it is except "6". sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `return` statement in the end of the script.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x.each{println it}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, use `findAll` to just then work on a list of interest:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].findAll { it % 2 == 0 }.each { println it }
```

Will just print the even numbers for example

#### Edit

Hang on, do you mean in the groovy console where it shows you the return value of the script in inverse type?

`each` returns the list it worked on, so you'll see the list after execution.

You can stop this by putting `null` at the end of your script (or something that returns `null` such as `println "done"`)

Comment: still printing values inside each closure. I tried as :::: x.each { i -> .... return null }

Answer (score 0):

Return from the closure to skip elements:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

list.each { i ->
  // skip uneven values
  if (!(i % 2 == 0)) return

  println i
}
```

Not that the return just skips the iteration step and does not return from the function the code is executed in.

Comment: i updated my post with my current output..I don't want these ==> * values to appear.